# Git remove files for commit but keep them on disk

Tags: git, bash, push, commit, git-checkout

I'm really new to GIT, and I only know how to add submodules, commit and push. I don't know what is a HEAD, neither a branch, an origin, a master.

I want to upload files to the server but the problem is I don't want to upload all files. GIT says to use `checkout -- <file_name>`, but if I checkout files that I don't want to commit, they will be modified, the edits that I made will disappear. I don't want this.

For example, I want to discard `../project.properties`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `..` is the root of your git working tree.

If the file is already committed, first do this:

```
git rm --cached ../project.properties
```

Then, in either case, do this, to prevent it being re-committed by someone (you, or another contributor):

```
echo project.properties >>../.gitignore
git add ../.gitignore
git commit -m 'Removing project.properties from repository'
```